# vb.net Selecting values and their string values

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
32 bob

50 willy

32 sarah

50 john
```

I have loaded this text file into my application:

```
 Private Sub browsebtn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles browsebtn1.Click
    Dim filedialog As New OpenFileDialog 'openfiledialog1 is now filedialog'
    filedialog.Filter = "Text Document|*.txt" 'filter the openfiledialogs file extension to txt only'
    filedialog.Title = "Select Bosvark Log File.." 'openfiledialog title'

    If filedialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 'if the file is chosen then..'

        filepath1.Text = filedialog.FileName 'filepath1 text is file path of selected file'
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(filepath1.Text, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText) 'richtextbox1 retrieves the file path and displays the document'

End If
End Sub
```

What I want to do is then have a button where I click it and a new richtextbox will display the data from a value that I have given, For example I have a textbox and in that textbox I type "50" the new richtextbox will display this:

```
willy

john
```

I do not expect code, All I need is some sort of reference or guidance. But if you want to give code then thats fine. I have been searching for this answer everywhere but no luck, I am familiar with how it is supposed to work because when I write php code and I use mysql tables, you can write a query that says "SELECT FROM users WHERE username = $username". Is there a similar function in vb.net?

Comment: why can't you store the contents of the file as a dictionary with keys as the numbers that you are talking about and the value being the list of names that match it - you could construct such dictionary by doing only one pass on the text file. Once you have the dictionary, it is as simple as dictionary(key) and you get your list of usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course VB.NET has a similar function, but, just like PHP, `SELECT` commands only work with a SQL database.  There is no built-in support for executing `SELECT` commands on text files.  If you do want to store the data in a SQL database, rather than a text file, so that you can execute `SELECT` commands, you'll need to look into either [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx).

If you do need to store the data as a text file, you can either parse the data yourself, for instance:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filedialog.FileName)
    Dim parts() As String = line.Split()
    Dim number As String = parts(0)
    Dim name As String = parts(1)
    'Do something with the parsed values, such as storing them in a List, or Dictionary
Next
```

Or, you can use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which will [parse the data for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That will only work, though, if your file is in a format that is supported by that class.

In either case, you'll need to load the data into some sort of data-structure in memory, such as a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), or [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).  It's impossible to say, with the limited information you've given, which data-structure makes the most sense for your particular situation.  Once you have the data loading into a data-structure, then you can write a method which outputs either all of that data, or a subset of that data, to a `RichTextBox`, as necessary.  How you do that will depend entirely on what data-structure you choose.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Could I use "Mid"? To select the specific words?? name = mid(name, 5, 3)??

Comment: Yes.  However, instead of using `Mid`, which is an old VB6-style function, you ought to be using the `String.SubString` method.  In other words, instead of `name = Mid(line, 5, 3)`, you should use `name = line.SubString(4, 3)`.  Note that the starting index for `Mid` is one-based whereas for `String.SubString` it's zero-based.